# How to create individual zip file for each of .py file

Tags: python, bash, shell

I need to create a bash script that create individual zip file for each of python file in the same directory.

I found the following command could create the zip with the file and original file extension. e.g created `test.py.zip` for `test.py`

`find . -name '*.py' -exec zip '{}.zip' '{}' \;`

How can I update the command to get rid of the original file extension. e.g. `test.zip` instead of `test.py.zip`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just use mv test.py.zip test.zip

Answer (score 2):

You can strip an extension using `basename <file> <extension>`.  There are a  variety of ways you could arrange to do that.

**Using a loop in `bash`**

For example, loop through the results from `find` and then zip the file:

```
for f in $(find . -name '*.py')
do 
    zip "$(basename "$f" .py).zip" "$f"
done
```

**Using a subshell in `find`**

Unfortunately we can't use `$(...)` in `find ... -exec` directly.  However we can always invoke a shell and do it there:

```
find . -name '*.py' -exec sh -c 'zip "$(basename "$0" .py)".zip "$0"' '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with `find`'s `-exec` option. You can use `bash`'s `while` loop and `sed` to process `find`'s output instead:

```
find . -name '*.py' -print | while read FILE; do zip `echo $FILE|sed 's/\py$//'`zip $FILE; done
```